# public/index.php does not show

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache2

I have a bit of a strange problem. I just got a dedicated server, an I pushed my code to my server. When I load any route or even /public/index.php, I get a 404 file not found error. I followed the tutorial on setting up a new virtual host in Apache and set up the configuration, as well as added AllowOverride to my apache2.httpd file. However, when I load any route or the public/index.php file, I get a 404 file not fond error.

I double checked my configuration file to make sure my DocumentRoot directory is correct. I also uploaded a phpinfo script to see if it would load anything. Still get a 404 error when I load test.php If there was an easy way to copy and paste my configuration file I would paste them. I tried installing Xsel, but I couldn't use it. I think everything is configured properly in apache2.conf as well as my .htaccess file anyway.

I am pretty sure this isn't a Laravel issue and more of a server issue...

EDIT: Apache's error.log file

```
[Mon Mar 06 20:28:16.776270 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 3934] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Mar 06 20:28:16.893620 2017] [:notice] [pid 3935] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Mon Mar 06 20:28:16.895966 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3935] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 06 20:28:16.895988 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3935] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:04.275540 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3935] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:05.285830 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 4934] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:05.307985 2017] [:notice] [pid 4935] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:05.310480 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4935] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:05.310505 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4935] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:10.868498 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4935] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:10.947828 2017] [:notice] [pid 4935] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Mon Mar 06 20:30:10.948068 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4935] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Added the error log. Don't understand whats going on...

Comment: What are the Apache configuration files?

Comment: by that I meant the .htaccess file and apache2.conf file

Comment: Can you paste you VirtualHost configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment. Just to be sure do html files work in your public directory. Try public/index.html first.